# Symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. Is it true that $$\sum_{i,j=1}^d x^i A^{i,j} x^j \leq ||x||^2 \sum_{i=1}^d A^{i,i}.$$ I was able to do this for $d=2$ by considering $x' = (-x_1,x_2)$ but it was messy and I don't see how to generalize it. Is there some tool I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: A question: $A$ is acting on ${\mathbb R}^{d}$ and the norm on this space is $\|(x_1, \ldots,x_d)\|=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+\cdots+x_{d}^{2}}$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, it can be diagonalized by orthogonal matrix $M$,
$$
A=M^TDM,\quad D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d),\quad\lambda_i\geq 0, i=1,\dots,d
$$
Then
$$
x^TAx=x^TM^TDMx=(Mx)^TD(Mx)=y^TDy,\quad y=Mx
$$
It is easy to see that
$$
y^TDy\leq\|y\|^2\lambda_\max\leq\|y\|^2\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i=\|y\|^2\sum_{i=1}^dA^{i,i}
$$
and $\|y\|=\|Mx\|=\|x\|$ since $M$ is orthogonal.